# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module scheduleApp due to:

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTMl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="scheduleApp">
<head>
<title>AngularJs Schedule</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/firebase.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container"  ng-controller="mainController">

    <div class="page-header text-center">

        <h1>Schedule City</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row times">
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">

        <h2>{{day.name}}</h2>
        <div class="time-slot" ng-repeat="slot in day.slots">
                    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module('scheduleApp',['firebase'])
.controller('mainController', function($scope){

var ref = new Firebase("https://torrid-inferno-884.firebaseIO.com/days");
var fb = $firebase(ref);
var syncObject = fb.$asObject();
syncObject.$bindTo($scope,'days');

  $scope.reset = function() {    

            fb.$set({
              monday: {
                name: 'Monday',
                slots: {
                  0900: {
                    time: '9:00am',
                    booked: false
                  },
                  0110: {
                    time: '11:00am',
                    booked: false
                  }
                }
              },
              tuesday: {
                name: 'Tuesday',
                slots: {
                  0900: {
                    time: '9:00am',
                    booked: false
                  },
                  0110: {
                    time: '11:00am',
                    booked: false
                  }
                }
              }
            });    

          };



});
```

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'scheduleApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Did you include your controller JS on the page?

Comment: Yes I have included.

Comment: Can you verify in the console the JS is being loaded? I don't see where you include it in the code above.

Comment: So sorry. I just noticed it now that I haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you messed up with the file loading sequence. firebasejs should be there before `angularfire.min.js` as it uses firebase.js code internally.

```
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="js/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/otherscripts.js"></script>
```

**Update**

Inject $firebase dependency in your controller function

```
.controller('mainController', function($scope, $firebase){
```

Comment: ReferenceError: $firebase is not defined

Comment: You need to inject `$firebase` in your controller like this - `.controller('mainController', function($scope, $firebase){ });`

Comment: Now I am not getting any output.